# React Native throw Network Error when using Axios or Fetch in android

Tags: android, react-native, https, axios, fetch

Hi i have this https api that behaves kinda weird, so i have this fetch/api function like this

my react native version

```
 "axios": "^0.21.1",
 "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
 "react": "17.0.1",
 "react-native": "0.64.1",
```

```js
 try {
      let result = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://my.service.com/authService/accounts/login',
        data: {
          userid: 'username',
          password: 'password',
        },
        headers: {
          ContentType: 'application/JSON',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      });
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, 'error');
    }
```

so when i test it with iOS simulator it works just fine. but when i test it with android it gives me this error[image]

is there any specific configuration for this case, (i've already use cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" but its not working since my api is HTTPS).

react-native-ssl-pinning it works on android but not working in iOS. and i dont really want to use theese library since autolinking is not working

update: i tried to implement this solution

```
package com.test; // replace app-name

import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientFactory;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomClientFactory implements OkHttpClientFactory {

        @Override
        public OkHttpClient createNewNetworkModuleClient() {
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .cipherSuites(CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256)
                .build();

        List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
        specs.add(spec);
        specs.add(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
        specs.add(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT);
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionSpecs(specs)
                .connectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer());
        return OkHttpClientProvider.enableTls12OnPreLollipop(client).build();
        }
}
```

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Build;
import com.test.CustomClientFactory;  // replace <app-name>
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
      OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(new CustomClientFactory());
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.test.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with axios
but the error still exists [image: axios]

with fetch
[image]

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: sadly no, so I use react-native-fetch-pinch-new and put server certificate in my projects

Comment: react-native-pinch-new. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is internet permission is added in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifext.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.exampleapp">
     
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```